# ¿Como podría automatizar ejecución proyecto FeatureIDE en Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

estoy haciendo un proyecto con FeatureIDE en eclipse, es programación orientada a características, y el plugin de eclipse va muy bien, pero no se utilizarlo fuera de eclipse.

Para poner en contexto, FeatureIDE permite construir un árbol de características y programarlo, y por sí solo genera un archivo de configuración el cual se puede editar en eclipse (es un xml).

Yo lo que quiero es, ya que tengo mi árbol programado y demás, generar el archivo de configuración por otra parte, meterlo en la carpeta correspondiente y ejecutar el proyecto por consola, pero veo que no puedo hacerlo ya que al pegar el correspondiente archivo de configuración, lo debo de abrir en eclipse, guardarlo (ctrl+s) y es entonces cuando FeatureIDE genera por si solo el main a ejecutar.

Ojalá me podáis ayudar, pongo la estructura del proyecto para que os hagáis una idea:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Decir también que para ejecutar el proyecto hay que hacer click derecho en el propio proyecto (no en el main) y ejecutarlo con java application.

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Existe un software que se llama AutoIt , te puede facilitar la automatización de procesos, tiene su propio lenguaje pero existe incluso librerías para programarlo con Java , es bastante sencillo.

Te dejo un link: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

Espero te sirva de ayuda ,

Un saludo.